# SQL server 2005 can't reference column that has been "casted"

Tags: casting

this query works:

```
select ist_id,  ist_opis , CAST(ist_sifra as float ) as sifra 
from IZOBRAZBENA_STOPNJA 
where ist_aktivno<>0 
order by sifra
```

but if I want to see only only when sifra = 5 I get "Invalid column name 'sifra'."

```
select ist_id,  ist_opis , CAST(ist_sifra as float ) as sifra 
from IZOBRAZBENA_STOPNJA 
where ist_aktivno<>0 and sifra = 5
order by sifra
```

I tryed wraping working sql statement in another select and then using "where sifra = 5" it also fails..

Comment: Have you tried the "CONVERT" command instead of "CAST"? check this link out:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is a fact.  you sould do something like

where ist_aktivno<>0 and ist_sifra = 5
or
where ist_aktivno<>0 and CAST(ist_sifra as float ) =5

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no column named sifra. You either cast in the where clause as well

```
select ist_id,  ist_opis , CAST(ist_sifra as float ) as sifra 
from IZOBRAZBENA_STOPNJA 
where ist_aktivno<>0 and CAST(ist_sifra as float ) = 5
order by sifra
```

or refer the uncasted column

```
select ist_id,  ist_opis , CAST(ist_sifra as float ) as sifra 
from IZOBRAZBENA_STOPNJA 
where ist_aktivno<>0 and ist_sifra = 5
order by sifra
```